# How to perform full text search on number fields in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, query-string

### Question:

Without converting a number field to a string, how can I perform a full text search on it?

I'm trying mimic the behavior of `_all` to dynamically convert a number field to a string when performing a query.

## Example.

### Setup:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/test/items/1 -d '{accountId : 12341234, name:"Bob"}'
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/test/items/2 -d '{accountId : 980987, name:"Marry"}'
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/test/items/3 -d '{accountId : 234234, name:"Daniel"}'
```

### Objective:

Find an `accountId` with the number 4.

### What I've done.

I tried these two queries but received 0 hits.

Queries:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/items/_search" -d '{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "accountId": "4"
    }
  }
}'

curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/items/_search" -d '{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "4"
    }
  }
}'
```

### Output:

```
{
    "took": 0,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

Comment: `{"query": {"query_string": {"query": "*4*" }}}` but, if I'm not mistaken, the query would be performed on `_all` which means that if you have an `accountId` set to 123 for example and the `name` to 'Mary4' it will still match.

Comment: A slightly better one, but the restriction from my first comment still stands (for example, `name` is "1234", `accountId` doesn't contain 4): `{"query": {"query_string": {"query": "/[0-9]*4[0-9]*/" }}}`

Comment: Searching with leading and trailing wildcards is going to be extremely slow on a large index. So I don't advice you to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest that you use the ngram tokenizer for that purpose.

Here is a code sample of what you might need. You would want to first set the analyzer settings with the tokenizer you wish to use.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test?pretty=true -d '{
  "settings":{
    "analysis":{
      "analyzer":{
        "my_ngram_analyzer":{
          "tokenizer":"my_ngram_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer":{
        "my_ngram_tokenizer":{
          "type":"nGram",
          "token_chars":[
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

More on Ngram Tokenizer [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html).

Then you should define the following mapping:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/items/_mapping?pretty=true -d '{
  "items":{
    "properties":{
      "accountId":{
        "analyzer":"my_ngram_analyzer",
        "type":"string"
      },
      "name":{
        "type":"string"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

The reason 'accountId' is a 'string' is that the Ngram tokenizer doesn't work on numeric fields.

Now you can query your index :

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/test/_search?pretty=true -d'
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "accountId",
      "query": "4"
    }
  }
}'
```

You can find [here](https://gist.github.com/eliasah/02ff901d75f67a43f75e) the bash script I used to test it.

**NB**: Of course this is just a demo on about how you can use the Ngram Tokenizer. I hope it will help

Comment: But you need the field to be "string". The question mentioned "without converting a number field to a string". Probably, this kind of requirement still needs some re-thinking of data structure, but still.

Comment: I skipped that part of the question. I'm sorry! But as for now, and quoting 'kimchy' : "There isn't really a meaning for an analyzer on numeric values. They either indexed or not." ([reference](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/analyzer-for-numeric-type-of-fields-td4020009.html)). And if you can't analyzer a numeric field, thus you can't tokenize it and you can't then make it take use of the full-text search features provided by Elasticsearch

Answer (score 7):

Create a multi-field, that will contain a number field and also a string for searching

```
PUT /test/items/_mapping
{
  "items" : {
    "properties" : {
      "accountId" : {
        "type" : "multi_field",
          "fields" : {
            "numeric" : {
              "type" : "integer",
              "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "text" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "index" : "analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Verify your mapping:

```
GET /test/items/_mapping
```

**Output**

```
{
   "test": {
      "mappings": {
         "items": {
            "properties": {
               "accountId": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "index": "no",
                  "fields": {
                     "numeric": {
                        "type": "integer"
                     },
                     "text": {
                        "type": "string"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Put your data into elastic search.

Now you can do a search as string, but you will get result as number:

```
GET /test/items/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "accountId.text",
      "query": "*4*"
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
{
   "took": 15,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 4,
      "successful": 4,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "items",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "accountId": 234234,
               "name": "Daniel"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "items",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "accountId": 12341234,
               "name": "Bob"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```